# Rooted phone - Cannot remove some bloatware

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, bloatware, 2.3.3-gingerbread

I have an LG Optimus Elite (Sprint/Ting) thats been rooted. Since its a Sprint phone, it had voluminous crapware, which an install of the NoBloat app took care of a good part of it but I still have a bunch that weren't seen in the NoBloat screen. Several of them are obvious Sprint crap (SprintID, SprintMusicPlus and SprintTV & Movies) but a few are Google (GooglePlayBooks, GooglePlayMovies & TV, and GooglePlayMusic).. I know at least a few are going to suggest putting ClockworkRecovery and a 3rd party ROM on the phone. I'd really love to do that very thing, but am running into the problem where all of the info I've googled on installling CWR on a LG Optimus Elite calls out putting it on a partition that doesn't seem to exist on *my* Elite when I do a "mount" .. I'm really shy about following the instructions that appear to me to be wrong.. The FAQ I'm referring to is at

http://androidforums.com/elite-all-things-root/620742-faq-guide-clockworkmod-optimus-elite.html

The Step 5 calls out "Type dd if=/sdcard/part_13_cwm_9_22_17_32.bin of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p14 and tap the [Enter] key" .. According to "mount", there is no /dev/block/mmcblk0p14 on this phone. I've put CWR on my old LG Optimus V with no questions/problems, so assume I'm comfortable with the rest of this procedure...

If anybody has input on either of these sub-problems, I'd sure appreciate a hand...

Dave

Comment: Have you tried something like Titanium Backup?

Answer (score 0):

I see your device has a Snapdragon chip.

Check to see if you have partitions that you can actually read by typing

```
su
ls /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/
```

If you see something called `recovery` there, then you're in luck.

```
su
dd if=/sdcard/part_13_cwm_9_22_17_32.bin of=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/recovery
```

If it isn't there, then you must try the one in the CWM thread again.
I've never heard of a device-specific nonexistent partition before, so perhaps you just typed it wrong or you forgot to `su`.

I apologize if this is not of any help.